# Connecting Active Directory to wso2 Identity Server

Tags: active-directory, wso2-identity-server

Im trying to connect my Active Directory as a user store of wso2 Identity Server 5.3.0 following this tutorial :  https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+an+Active+Directory+User+Store

my Active directory uses on ldap and not ldaps.

After running the wso2 Identity Server Im trying to login as admin in the management console (localhost:9443/carbon) but I get this error:

```
04-20 10:23:39,691] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for user tomer
[2017-04-20 10:23:39,691] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  value after escaping special characters in tomer : tomer
[2017-04-20 10:23:39,694] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  User: tomer exist: true
[2017-04-20 10:23:39,696] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for user tomer
[2017-04-20 10:23:39,697] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  value after escaping special characters in tomer : tomer
[2017-04-20 10:23:39,697] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  User: tomer exist: true
[2017-04-20 10:23:39,697] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for user tomer
[2017-04-20 10:23:39,697] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  value after escaping special characters in tomer : tomer
[2017-04-20 10:23:39,697] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  User: tomer exist: true
[2017-04-20 10:23:39,698] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} -  Error occurred while accessing Java Security Manager Privilege Block
[2017-04-20 10:23:39,699] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationAdmin} -  System error while Authenticating/Authorizing User : Error when handling event : PRE_AUTHENTICATION
```

I see the authentication is againest ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager but this user store is commented out in user-mgt.xml file.

anybody knows what to do?

Comment: To get a better understanding of the error shall we enable some more debug logs? Go to repository/conf/log4j.properties and uncomment #log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.user.core=DEBUG line. Update the question with the logs you get when you try to login

Comment: hi farasath. Ive updated the log.

Comment: is it possible for you to attach the complete log file. upload it somewhere and add the link here?

Comment: should I enable the java security manager in order for it to work? https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Enabling+Java+Security+Manager